# Responsive Menu (CSS Issue) [Space Between top level Menus]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, css-transitions

I`m new to responsive UI`s , Actually i`m trying to create a responsive menu from json data using angular js.

When my screen size is full then it works fine , but when my screen max-width is less than 500px then menu is not getting displayed properly  there are spaces between dropdown-menus .

Please let me know where i`m making the mistake.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Angular Test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>

    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    body {
      font: 300 15px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
      background: #333;
      margin: 15px;
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-size: 45px;
      font-weight: 100;
      letter-spacing: 15px;
      text-align: center;
      color:gray;
    }
    h3{
    
    color:gray;
    
    }
    
    h1,
    #main_content,
    #dog_link {
      padding: 15px;
    }
    
    p {
      margin: 15px 0;
    }
    
    a {
      color: #06c;
    }
    
    #main_nav ul {
      background: white;
      float: left;
      -webkit-transition: .5s;
      transition: .5s;
    }
    
    #main_nav li {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      width: 150px;
      list-style: none;
      -webkit-transition: .5s;
      transition: .5s;
    }
    
    #main_nav>ul>li>a,
    h1 {
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    #main_nav a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 5px 15px;
      color: #000;
    }
    
    #main_nav ul ul {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 100%;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    #main_nav ul ul ul {
      left: 100%;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    #main_nav li:hover,
    #main_nav li:hover li {
      background: #ddd;
    }
    
    #main_nav li li:hover,
    #main_nav li li:hover li {
      background: #bbb;
    }
    
    #main_nav li li li:hover {
      background: #999;
    }
    
    #main_nav li:hover>ul {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }
 
    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    
      li { display: block; border-bottom: 1px #D25458 solid; } li:last-child { border-bottom: none; }  
    
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    body {
      font: 300 15px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
      background: gray;
      margin: 15px;
      color:white;
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-size: 25px;
      font-weight: 100;
      letter-spacing: 5px;
      text-align: center;
      color:#333;
    }
    h3{
    
    color:gray;
    
    }
    
    h1,
    #main_content,
    #dog_link {
      padding: 15px;
    }
    
    p {
      margin: 15px 0;
    }
    
    a {
      color: #06c;
    }
    
    #main_nav ul {
      background: white;
      float: left;
      -webkit-transition: .5s;
      transition: .5s;
    }
    
    #main_nav li {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      width: 150px;
      list-style: none;
      -webkit-transition: .5s;
      transition: .5s;
    }

    
    #main_nav>ul>li>a,
    h1 {
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    #main_nav a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 5px 15px;
      color: #000;
    }
    
    #main_nav ul ul {
      position: relative;
      left: 0;
      top: 100%;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    #main_nav ul ul ul {
      left: 100%;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    #main_nav li:hover,
    #main_nav li:hover li {
      background: #ddd;
    }

    
    #main_nav li li:hover,
    #main_nav li li:hover li {
      background: #bbb;
    }
    
    #main_nav li li li:hover {
      background: #999;
    }
    
    #main_nav li:hover>ul {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
#animation {-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;}
</style>
<script>
history.forward();
var helloAjaxApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


helloAjaxApp.controller("myCtrl3", [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";

    $scope.sendGet3 = function() {
        
            $scope.menus = [{"name":"home","url":"#","submenus":[]},{"name":"enrollment","url":"#","submenus":[{"name":"New Enrollment","url":"#","submenus":[{"name":"Ekyc","url":"#"},{"name":"Non_ekyc","url":"#"}]},{"name":"Modify_Old ","url":"#","submenus":[{"name":"Ekyc","url":"#"},{"name":"Non-Ekyc","url":"#"}]}]},{"name":"User Module","url":"#","submenus":[{"name":"Create","url":"#","submenus":[]},{"name":"Modify","url":"#","submenus":[{"name":"Operator","url":"#"},{"name":"BC","url":"#"}]},{"name":"Delete","url":"#","submenus":[]}]},{"name":"Reports","url":"#","submenus":[{"name":"Summery_Reports","url":"#","submenus":[{"name":"Accounts Opened","url":"#"},{"name":"Enrollments","url":"#"}]},{"name":"General Report","url":"#","submenus":[]}]}];
        };
} ]);

 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Enrollment System</h1>


      <div ng-app="myApp"> 
      

    <div ng-init="sendGet3()" ng-controller="myCtrl3" >
      <nav id="main_nav">
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="menu in menus"><a href="{{menu.url}}">{{menu.name}}</a>
            <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="submenu1 in menu.submenus"><a href="{{submenu1.url}}">{{submenu1.name}}</a>
                <ul>
                  <li ng-repeat="submenu2 in submenu1.submenus"><a href="{{submenu2.url}}">{{submenu2.name}}</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      
      
    </div>  
 
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What behavior is it supposed to have ? I noticed you are using `visibility: hidden` to hide your `<ul>`submenus, you might want to use `display:none`  and `display: block|inline-block` to make it reappear.
Also note that on mobile devices an hidden menu toggled on hover is an issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help.

```css
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    body {
      font: 300 15px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
      background: #333;
      margin: 15px;
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-size: 45px;
      font-weight: 100;
      letter-spacing: 15px;
      text-align: center;
      color:gray;
    }
    h3{
    
    color:gray;
    
    }
    
    h1,
    #main_content,
    #dog_link {
      padding: 15px;
    }
    
    p {
      margin: 15px 0;
    }
    
    a {
      color: #06c;
    }
    
    #main_nav ul {
      background: white;
      float: left;
      -webkit-transition: .5s;
      transition: .5s;
    }
    
    #main_nav li {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      width: 150px;
      list-style: none;
      -webkit-transition: .5s;
      transition: .5s;
    }
    
    #main_nav>ul>li>a,
    h1 {
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    #main_nav a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 5px 15px;
      color: #000;
    }
    
    #main_nav ul ul {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 100%;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    #main_nav ul ul ul {
      left: 100%;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    #main_nav li:hover,
    #main_nav li:hover li {
      background: #ddd;
    }
    
    #main_nav li li:hover,
    #main_nav li li:hover li {
      background: #bbb;
    }
    
    #main_nav li li li:hover {
      background: #999;
    }
    
    #main_nav li:hover>ul {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }
 
    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    
     #main_nav li { display: block; border-bottom: 1px #D25458 solid; } li:last-child { border-bottom: none; }  
    
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    body {
      font: 300 15px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
      background: gray;
      margin: 15px;
      color:white;
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-size: 25px;
      font-weight: 100;
      letter-spacing: 5px;
      text-align: center;
      color:#333;
    }
    h3{
    
    color:gray;
    
    }
    
    h1,
    #main_content,
    #dog_link {
      padding: 15px;
    }
    
    p {
      margin: 15px 0;
    }
    
    a {
      color: #06c;
    }
    
    #main_nav ul {
      background: white;
      float: none !important;
      -webkit-transition: .5s;
      transition: .5s;
    }
    
    #main_nav li {
      position: relative;
      list-style: none;
      -webkit-transition: .5s;
      transition: .5s;
      float: none;
      width: auto;
    }

    
    #main_nav>ul>li>a,
    h1 {
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    #main_nav a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 5px 15px;
      color: #000;
    }
    
    #main_nav ul ul {
      position: relative;
      left: 0;
      top: 100%;
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    #main_nav ul ul ul {
      left: 100%;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    #main_nav li:hover,
    #main_nav li:hover li {
      background: #ddd;
    }

    
    #main_nav li li:hover,
    #main_nav li li:hover li {
      background: #bbb;
    }
    
    #main_nav li li li:hover {
      background: #999;
    }
    
    #main_nav li ul {
      position: static !important;
    }
    
    #main_nav li:hover>ul {
      max-height: 400px;
    }
}
#animation {-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Angular Test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>

    
</style>
<script>
history.forward();
var helloAjaxApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


helloAjaxApp.controller("myCtrl3", [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";

    $scope.sendGet3 = function() {
        
            $scope.menus = [{"name":"home","url":"#","submenus":[]},{"name":"enrollment","url":"#","submenus":[{"name":"New Enrollment","url":"#","submenus":[{"name":"Ekyc","url":"#"},{"name":"Non_ekyc","url":"#"}]},{"name":"Modify_Old ","url":"#","submenus":[{"name":"Ekyc","url":"#"},{"name":"Non-Ekyc","url":"#"}]}]},{"name":"User Module","url":"#","submenus":[{"name":"Create","url":"#","submenus":[]},{"name":"Modify","url":"#","submenus":[{"name":"Operator","url":"#"},{"name":"BC","url":"#"}]},{"name":"Delete","url":"#","submenus":[]}]},{"name":"Reports","url":"#","submenus":[{"name":"Summery_Reports","url":"#","submenus":[{"name":"Accounts Opened","url":"#"},{"name":"Enrollments","url":"#"}]},{"name":"General Report","url":"#","submenus":[]}]}];
        };
} ]);

 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Enrollment System</h1>


      <div ng-app="myApp"> 
      

    <div ng-init="sendGet3()" ng-controller="myCtrl3" >
      <nav id="main_nav">
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="menu in menus"><a href="{{menu.url}}">{{menu.name}}</a>
            <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="submenu1 in menu.submenus"><a href="{{submenu1.url}}">{{submenu1.name}}</a>
                <ul>
                  <li ng-repeat="submenu2 in submenu1.submenus"><a href="{{submenu2.url}}">{{submenu2.name}}</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      
      
    </div>  
 
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Or can you show desired result what do you need actually?

Comment: Actually ,what i want is ,when the screen size goes 500 px then ,drop down menus should display only on hover like what is happening in full screen view, there should not be spaces for dropdowns.. You can see this snippet in 500 px

Answer (score 0):

Inside your media query for screen size 500px, add following style

```css
#main_nav ul ul>li{
  height:30px;
 }
```

Comment: by using this also there are spaces between top level menus , if screen width is 500 px